# send parameters from a service to service host

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, servicehost

I have an interface for setting parameters for a service managed by a service host. When I submit the changes I want to reconfigure the service to use the new values.

```
public interface IServicesConfig
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "set", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    Stream SetParameters(Parameters parameters);
}
```

where Parameters is my data contract class and has string members;

Is this possible to send my parameters list without specifying each of them inside UriTemplate (set?param1={param1}&...) ?